# Show the existence of finding the optimal points of the given dynamical system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, self-learning

$$\frac{x_{t+1}}{x_t}=1-b\left(\frac{x_t}{y_t}-a\right)$$
$$y_{t+1}+x_t=hy_t+k$$

Here, all parameters $(b,a,h,k)$ are strictly positive. And $h>1$.

What are the conditions on parameters such that nontrivial optimal points exists.

———

What I did is that

the optimal (steady state) is found when $x_{t+1}=x_t=x^*$ and $y_{t+1}=y_t=y^*$ are satisfied.

And in this way, I found that $$(x^*,y^*)=\left(\frac{ak}{a-(h-1)}, \frac{k}{a-(h-1)}\right)$$ are the optimal points which exists when $a>h-1$.

I cannot find any condition on parameters expect for this.

Please share your ideas with me and show me a way to find conditions.

Comment: Why do you need $a>h-1$? Isn't it enough that $a \neq h-1$?

Comment: In fact, $x$ represents consumption and $y$ represents wealth. So, I think that the optimal points of consumption and wealth should be positive. So, I use this inequality. But I am not sure. What is your opinion ? @LukasRollier

Comment: Is this way without my assumption true? Did I find optimal values correctly? @LukasRollier

Comment: For $a > h-1$ you can say that the equilibrium is **feasible**. Existence is another topic.

Comment: You're right in finding the optimal values. You could argue that consumption and wealth may be negative, but probably best to keep them positive indeed.

Comment: @the_candyman, you can check that the point he has found is indeed an equilibrium

Comment: Hmmm, well how can I discuss the existence? I have no idea. Please help me to do that. Thanks a lot dear @the_candyman

Comment: Thanks @LukasRollier for your reply to me.

Comment: Existence is related to the well-posedness of the equilibrium. In particular, for $a=h-1$, it does not exist (i.e. division by $0$ is not a well-posed mathematical operation). Feasibility is related to the "meaning" of the variable $x$ and $y$. Since they represent consumption and wealth, then you can assume that they are positive number. Hence, a negative valued equilibrium obtained for $a <h-1$ is not relevant or not feasible.

Comment: Well, which conditions should be satisfied for the existence? And why? Please expand your answer. I could not understand enough. Sorry:( I am just interested in existence dear @the_candyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibria of you dynamical system can be found by setting $x_{t+1}=x_{t} = x^*$ and  $y_{t+1}=y_{t} = y^*$.

The equilibrium is

$$(x^*,y^*)=\left(\frac{ak}{a-(h-1)}, \frac{k}{a-(h-1)}\right).$$

To be an equilibrium, then $(x^*,y^*) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. It is straightforward to notice that for $a = h-1$, the denominators of both $x^*$ and $y^*$ is $0$. Recall that dividing any number (in this case, $ak$ and $k$) by $0$ is not a well-posed mathematical operation. Hence, for $a=h-1$, the equilibrium $(x^*,y^*)$ is not defined (or equivalently it does not exist, or equivalently the equilibrium corresponds to "infinity").

Comment: So, it must be $a\not= h-1$. Is this enough to show existence? Well alright!